# How to order an individiual item instead of a set?

Tags: usage, word-requests, word-usage

I say 「セット」 when I order a set, and I say 「これだけ」 when I just want to order an individual item.

Is there any common way to order an individual item instead of a set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [単品【たんぴん】](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%8D%98%E5%93%81). Perhaps this is the only word you would need in this situation.

> - チーズバーガー、単品で。
> - 単品のチーズバーガーを2つ。